# XML To use to register a new UPNP device

Tags: c#, .net, xml, upnp

I'm trying to register a new UPNP device(and trying to understand how it works by the way).

For now, I'm just trying to create a simple test, to have something working and build from there.

I'm using the UPnP Device host for now, I've the following code:

```
IUPnPRegistrar registrar = (IUPnPRegistrar)new UPnPRegistrarClass();
String description = GetDescription();
String path = GetPath();
registrar.RegisterDevice(description, "Test1", "Init", "Container", path, 900);
```

The GetDescription method return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <UDN>@@UDN@@</UDN>
        <friendlyName>Test device</friendlyName>
        <deviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:XmsHostService:1</deviceType>
        <manufacturer>Test</manufacturer>
        <manufacturerURL>http://www.test.com</manufacturerURL>
        <modelName>Test model name</modelName>
        <modelNumber>0.1</modelNumber>
        <modelDescription>Test device</modelDescription>
        <modelURL>http://www.test.com/test-model-url</modelURL>
        <serialNumber>0000001</serialNumber>
        <UPC>00000-00001</UPC>
        <serviceList>
            <service>
                <serviceType>urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:XmsHost:1</serviceType>
                <serviceId>urn:upnp-org:serviceId:XmsHost</serviceId>
                <controlURL></controlURL>
                <eventSubURL></eventSubURL>
                <SCPDURL>serviceDescription.xml</SCPDURL>
            </service>
        </serviceList>
    </device>
</root>
```

And my C:\upnphost\service.xml contains the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scpd xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <actionList>
        <action>
            <name>GetPort</name>
            <argumentList>
                <argument>
                    <name>_ReturnValue</name>
                    <direction>out</direction>
                    <retval />
                    <relatedStateVariable>A_ARG_TYPE_GetPort_RetType</relatedStateVariable>
                </argument>
            </argumentList>
        </action>
    </actionList>
    <serviceStateTable>
        <stateVariable sendEvents="no">
            <name>A_ARG_TYPE_GetPort_RetType</name>
            <dataType>ui4</dataType>
        </stateVariable>
        <stateVariable sendEvents="no">
            <name>Port</name>
            <dataType>ui4</dataType>
        </stateVariable>
    </serviceStateTable>
</scpd>
```

So, first, does this xml code looks right?

When I call the register device, I got this exception:

```
    System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=UPnPHostLib
  StackTrace:
       at UPnPHostLib.IUPnPRegistrar.RegisterDevice(String bstrXMLDesc, String bstrProgIDDeviceControlClass, String bstrInitString, String bstrContainerId, String bstrResourcePath, Int32 nLifeTime)
       at UPnPHosterTester.Hoster.Start() in E:\Dev\Discovery\XMS_SW_Discovery_B\Solution\UPnPHosterTester\Hoster.cs:line 32
       at UPnPHosterTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Dev\Discovery\XMS_SW_Discovery_B\Solution\UPnPHosterTester\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

But I don't see what can be wrong, the 900 is the min value accepted. Other linked question: I know that I have to implement the IUPnPDeviceControl interface and insert in my previous code instead of Test1, but I don't know what I should return in the GetServiceObject

**EDIT**
Here is the GetDescription method:

```
private string GetDescription()
{
    string xml = File.OpenText("DeviceDescription.xml").ReadToEnd();
    xml = xml.Replace("@@UDN@@", "uuid:" +Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    return xml;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I tried, as recommended to remove all non-mandatory properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
    </specVersion>
    <device>
        <UDN>@@UDN@@</UDN>
        <friendlyName>Test device</friendlyName>
        <deviceType>urn:test-com:device:HostDevice:1</deviceType>
        <manufacturer>Test</manufacturer>
        <modelName>Test model name</modelName>
    </device>
</root>
```

But I still have the exact same error

**Edit 3**
I did found that there is an utility to check the good structure of the service xml file(not the device :() here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381938(v=vs.85).aspx You can use it with VS studio command prompt: `validatesd.exe`. It validates my service

Comment: Please stop editing your post away from the original title. Now it doesn't even refer to the XML. You don't have a problem with XML anymore but with Win32 IUPnP specific function parameters. My answer was answering the original question.

Comment: @PavelZdenek I think it's related to the XML content, because I don't see what can be out of range with my c# call. In all case, I'm sorry, I saw a little too late that I didn't posted the last error I was having.

Comment: Ok i see. Then try do what i suggested in the answer. Remove everything not REQUIRED until it works and then add back. Most importantly, you don't need the `services`.

Comment: @PavelZdenek: I did try that, but it didn't changed anything :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM Object progid must correspond to something real, ie: "Test1" must be a valid COM object registered in the current registry for the RegisterDevice call to succeed.

Comment: In fact it's not test1 that I've but the "Namespace.Class" that I've. But like I understand, I'm supposed to register it, how?

Comment: This is another question. You can create a COM object in .NET. You can google for this. For example: http://www45.brinkster.com/b3ck/code/dllcreation.html

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that I've to register this Class with the IUPnPRegistrar. But if I'm in the same project, is this still mandatory? It should find the class directly, no?

Comment: I've read your link, but I'm not sure to understand, it's mandatory to register this library? Can't it just be in the same directory? Because it will deployed on a lot of computer, and we would like to keep our install clean(do not touch the GAC)

Comment: I'm closing this because the original question is answered and you really deserve to be rewarded for that, but my global problem isn't solved yet and I would appreciate if you could look an eye on the current problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746725/upnp-declare-a-service-on-upnp-using-com

Answer (score 1):

You figured out the XML header fast. This was already written:

> If your posted device XML is REALLY complete, then you are missing XML
>   header:
>        This is mandatory not only for the UPnP scope, but for XML in general.

If your posting is not complete and you have the header, i would start with leaving out all OPTIONAL elements. Leave out `serviceList`, `presentationURL`, `UPC`, `serialNumber`, and probably more. In case you didn't know, [mandatory spec is here](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf). Off the top of my head, i think UDN also has a mandatory format (starting with `uuid:`), but you have left the code in your post, not the result string, so i can't know whether you're doing it right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I updated my question with the content of the GetDescription method, it replaces the @@UDN@@ by a GUID with uuid:, so I think this one is ok. I tried to remove all properties you indicate me, ... But it doesn't change the exception. I also read that if it's custom types, we have to specify a different "urn" for device type by example, I did this, but it still doesn't change anything. I will post in one sec the current XML I've